# I need to fetch value from a YAML file using Robot Framework

Tags: python, json, yaml, robotframework

I am trying to substitute value inside my YAML file but unable to write a proper string using robot framework.

```
"patch_id_bw_data":
    "pronghornResponseBody":
        "shimBehaviourHeader":
            "destinationURL": ""
            "method": "PATCH"
            "targetName": "naas"
        "customHeaders": {}
        "responseBody":
            - "op": "replace"
              "path": "/serviceCharacteristic"
              "value":
                  - "name": "bandwidth"
                    "value": ""
```

Need to subsitute 200 in the `last--> "value": "200"`
Trying to do with the below syntax. But unable to subsitute:

Set To Dictionary    `${patch_id_bw_data.pronghornResponseBody.responseBody[0].value}`     value=200M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Here's a way to get it up and running:

First install the PyYAML python library via command line by running the following Python command:
`py -m pip install PyYAML`
You may also want to check out the `PyYAML` documentation:
https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

And here is an example `.robot` file for doing what was requested:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  yaml
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Load YAML into Robot and edit it
  ${YAML}=  Get File  ${CURDIR}${/}data.yaml
  ${LOADED}=  yaml.Safe Load  ${YAML}
  Set To Dictionary  ${LOADED}[patch_id_bw_data][pronghornResponseBody][responseBody][0][value][0]  value=200
  ${OUTPUT}=  yaml.Dump  ${LOADED}
  Create File  newdata.yaml  ${OUTPUT}
```

`${OUTPUT}` will contain the new edited yaml data already if you wish to use it inside of the test but here in the example we save it to a new file with the `Create File` keyword.

Before running this Robot Framework test make sure you have a `data.yaml` file included in the test folder containing the sample data you gave in the question. After running the Robot test there will be a new file `newdata.yaml` in the folder containing `200` in the correct value field.